# React components conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to conditionally render a component upon some state attribute changes and facing some array says "Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...?". Though I looked for it and is because while returning  multiple sibling JSX elements in an incorrect manner. I don't see any such in my code. Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong while trying to render another component.

```
const Data = [
    new Feature({ ID: 101, NAME: 'ABC1' }), 
    new Feature({ ID: 102, NAME: 'XYZ2' )),
    new Feature({ ID: 103, NAME: 'PQS3'})
];
class Editor extends React.Component{
    constructor(props, context){
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            selectedF: null,
            fmu: null,
            mode: props.mode || C.MODE_VIEW,
            overview: false
        } 
    }

    handleClick = (event) => {
        const fid = event.target.value
        this.setState({ selectedF: fid });
    }

    display = () => {
        for(let i=0; i<Data.length; i++){
            if(this.state.selectedF == Data[i].get('ID'))
                {
                const data = Data[i].getProperties();
                this.setState({
                    fmu: data,
                    overview: true
                });

                }       
        }
    }
     render(){
        return (
                <React.Fragment>
            <div className="sidebarContainer">
            {this.state.overview ? <Overview /> :
                <Tab.Container id="sidebar">
                <div className="bottomToolbar" style={{display: "flex"}}>
                  <div>
                  <ButtonToolbar>
                    <Button variant="primary">CREATE</Button>
                    <Button variant="primary" onClick={this.display}>VIEW</Button>
                </ButtonToolbar>
                 </div>
                 </div>
                  <ListGroup>
                  {Data.map((f, id) => {
                      return (<ListGroup.Item 
                              action href="" 
                              key={f.get('ID')}
                              value = {f.get('ID')}
                              onClick={this.handleClick}
                              >
                              {f.get('NAME')}
                              </ListGroup.Item>
                              )
                  })}
                  </ListGroup> 
                  <Tab.Content style={{ flex: "1 1 auto", position: "relative"}}>
                  <Tab.Pane eventKey="">

                  </Tab.Pane>
                </Tab.Content>
          </Tab.Container>  
}         
                </div> 

            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }


}
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError:Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>? (72:16)
  71 |          {this.state.overview ? <Overview /> :
> 72 |                 <Tab.Container id="sidebar">
     |                 ^
  73 |                 <div className="bottomToolbar" style={{display: "flex"}}>
  74 |                <div>
  75 |                <ButtonToolbar>
```

I am trying to hide JSX of Editor component on VIEW button click, and render Overview component, depending on the value of state attribute called "overview".

Comment: can you create a sandbox for it so its easy to debug ?

Comment: where is `Data` defined? Also `id` is not used at all in your example

Comment: @DamianGreen I added the data...please see updated question

Comment: What is the type of `Feature` ?

Comment: @Meana if you would create a sandbox it would be much easier to help

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the result of `f.get('NAME')` returns multiple fragments. But we can't see the type of your array from your example.

Answer (score 0):

There's an extra '}' in `</React.Fragment>}`.

Please remove that and everything will be okay.

**EDIT**: And you need to add `()` wrapper like

```
{
  this.state.overview ? <Overview /> :
   (<Tab.Container>
      ...
    </Tab.container>)
}
```

Comment: @Antonia I added that bracket in relation to the `{this.state.overview ? <Overview /> :`  removing it does not helps

Comment: @Antonia sorry my mistake..I removed the other bracket ...issue still persist..Maybe I can show which line actually error lies                                            `71 |       {this.state.fmuoverview ? <FmuOverview /> :
 
> 73 |                 <Tab.Container id="sidebar">
     |                 ^
  74 |                 <div className="bottomToolbar" style={{display: "flex"}}>
  75 |          <div>
  76 |          <ButtonToolbar>`

Comment: @Antonia if it helps locating.

Comment: @Antonia added please check

Comment: @Antonia..please leave that,,,it is changed name of component.

Comment: @Antonia it helps to get rid of the error but my application starts breaking as I can not render my Editor component now even :(

Comment: @Meana Could you please make snippet or codepen of your issue? It could be better to find the issue correctly.

Comment: @Antonia it is difficult for me to make codepen because the `Data`is open layers features objects. I am not sure if I can import open layers in codepen

Comment: @Antonia Can you please just make me sure that my approach for rendering another component is correct??

Comment: @Meana Actually, i couldn't find what is the real issue on your side. And I hope that you try to find the issue by adding or removing one by one line. And there's no issues in rendering your component according to your current codes. Thanks.

Comment: @Antonia So it works now, I enclosed all the JSX i wanted to hide inside 1 div and it works. Still wondering what was wrong with `Tab.Container`...Anyways, Thank You